# Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES) while connecting to the MySQL server

Tags: permissions, mysql

Tried yesterday to update my 16.04 box with `sudo apt upgrade`. Process finished with the above error. Tried solutions that exist in the forum but nothing worked. So I tried to uninstall and reinstall mysql using the following method

```
sudo purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt autoremove
rm -R /etc/mysql
rm -R ~/.mysql
```

restarted and then tried to re-install mysql

```
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

but got the same error. Now I cannot even login to mysql because my user doesn't have access. How can I deal with this?

Comment: You could add also rm -R /var/lib/mysql knowing that that would wipe out all the databases in the system, and try the reinstall again.

Answer (score 0):

First stop the service

1. sudo service mysql stop

We avoided asking for the password

2. mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &

Login

3. mysql -u root

We select mysql database

4. use mysql;

Then change the password

5. update user set password=PASSWORD("newpassword") where user='root';
6. flush privileges;

Exit

7. quit;

By last

8. service mysql stop
9. service mysql start

Access again with the new password and root user.

To change the password of your user, debian-sys-maint repeats step 5.

Forgive my English is not my native language